# What is the method to install CryptoTE on 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, encryption, gtk

What is the method to install CryptoTE on 16.04?

[Link to the instructions on installing CryptoTE on Ubuntu](https://panthema.net/2009/cryptote/linux-binary.html#ubuntu)

Following those instructions I have the following error:

```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install cryptote

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cryptote : Depends: libwxbase2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1) but it is not installable
            Depends: libwxgtk2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Update:** 
A commenter, M. Becerra, provided me with links to libwxbase2.8-0 and libwxgtk2.8-0. After installing them CryptoTE can be invoked from the Dash but it fails to run. Instead it shows a busy cursor for a few seconds and then the busy cursor disappears. Invoking `cryptote` from the command line results in the following print.

```
Fatal Error: Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected.
The library used 2.8 (no debug,Unicode,compiler with C++ ABI 1009,wx containers,compatible with 2.6),
and CryptoTE used 2.8 (no debug,Unicode,compiler with C++ ABI 1002,wx containers,compatible with 2.6).
Aborted (core dumped)
```

ABI means Application Binary Interface so it appears that the CryptoTE needs to invoke a ABI 1002 library but the library I have is compiled to be a ABI 1009 library.

Comment: Did you try install those packages from [here](https://pkgs.org/download/libwxbase2.8-0) (libwxbase2.8-0) and [here](https://pkgs.org/download/libwxgtk2.8-0) (libwxgtk2.8-0) the ones for 16.04?

Comment: I've installed what you linked. When I invoke CryptoTE from the dash it does the busy cursor for a while and then the busy cursor disappears. That's all.

Comment: Alternate approach: Use a *maintained* and *readily packaged* program that fulfils the same purpose. `qtpass` is available in the official repository for 16.04

Comment: What happens if you do it from terminal?

Comment: @M.Becerra, I uninstalled the Xenial versions of libwxbase2.8-0 and libwxgtk2.8-0 and installed the Trusty versions. CryptoTE is now working. If you post this as an answer I will award it.

Comment: Done! I'm glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries you need (version for Trusty) can be downloaded from here: [libwxbase2.8-0](https://pkgs.org/download/libwxbase2.8-0) and [libwxgtk2.8-0](https://pkgs.org/download/libwxgtk2.8-0).

- Download them both.
- Uninstall/Remove the Xenial versions for the libraries so they cause no trouble.
- Install the proper version of the libraries for your Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: The developer's website shows support up to and including 12.04 (Precise). However, CryptoTE works with 14.04 (Trusty) but not 16.04 (Xenial). That is the hint that the Trusty versions of libwxbase2.8-0 and libwxgtk2.8-0 are suitable.